# How to fix 'User does not have permission to query table XYZ.' in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to do a BQ query via the `bq` command.

Here is my command:

```
bq query    --application_default_credential_file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  
  --nouse_legacy_sql 'SELECT * FROM `my_project.data.Document` limit 100'
```

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` points to a credential file. I can use this variable to enable `gcloud` command to access my project's resources.

The query runs OK if I run it directly in bigquery query UI. I log in as myself.

However `bq`  failed with this error `Access Denied: Table my_project:data.Document: User does not have permission to query table
my_project:data.Document.`

I have granted these roles to the id, a service account, contained in the credential file:

[image]

Did I miss any role/permission?

Comment: I had this issue with the dbt BigQuery permissions and adding "BigQuery Data Owner" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be aware of the fact that `bq` executor's  [authorization](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#deprecated_bq_authorization_flags) flags have been deprecated and no longer used, hence flag `--application_default_credential_file` is more like redundant in your initial `bq query` command. Generally, `bq` authorization parameters sometimes interfered with the `gcloud` credential [settings](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_user_account) causing unpredictable results. According to the official guidelines you should follow regular SDK instructions to perform authorization setup:

> The bq authorization flags are deprecated. To configure authorization
>   for the bq command-line tool, see [Authorizing Cloud SDK tools](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing).

[Default](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#default_service_accounts) `@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` App Engine service account has granted [*primitive*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-primitive-roles) `Editor` role, admitting that it has access to all resources, additional `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` and `roles/bigquery.user` permissions are quite needless here.

Comment: Tested. roles/bigquery.dataViewer and roles/bigquery.user is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be two things:

1. user doesn't have access to the table itself and
2. user doesn't have querying permissions in the project.

To solve 1. I've often relied on the UI. Go to the dataset and, three dots and click share. Here's an example from my console;
[image]
There you can add the service account you're authenticating with to give it access to the data.

To solve 2, you need the service account to have the right role in the project to run jobs (at least that's what I've used so far to run queries without giving service accounts editor or owner roles). Go to IAM, select the service account and give it the role of **BiqQuery Job User**
[image]

This should be the most granular way to grant it access, without any unnecessary scopes.